# Syntastic check with remote for vim + vagrant

Tags: python, vim, syntastic

I'm using vim locally to edit files on my Mac host. These files are then synced using nfs to a vm (setup with Vagrant) that includes all of the dependencies. The vm is currently where the tests are run and where I would like to setup linting to run.

Is there a way to have syntastic run a checker on a remote machine? I want to do this for a few reasons:

1. The python dependencies are all setup correctly on the VM.
2. Syntastic + pylint runs super slow on the host.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't simply use Vim *in* the virtual machine?

Comment: primarily because i have many plugins and setup vim just so on the host and the vms come and go frequently so it would just be a pain to import dotfiles and vim bundles every time.

Comment: `$ git clone <url> ~/.vim` is a pain?

Comment: Syntastic can't check remote files.